# Manipulating cells within a group based on value in another cell

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data.frame in the following format:

```
CowId    Bacillus    Week
1234     1           Week1
1234     0           Week2
1234     0           Week3
1234     0           Week4
```

If a cow is bacillus-positive (yes=1, no=0) on Week1, then I want to change remaining values within this column to 1, as so:

```
CowId    Bacillus    Week
1234     1           Week1
1234     1           Week2
1234     1           Week3
1234     1           Week4
```

I tried the following, but unsure how to proceed after determining the infection status of Week1 cows:

```
dt %>%
    group_by(CowId) %>%
    mutate(Bacillus = ifelse(Week == "Week1" & Bacillus, 1,
                          ifelse(Week != "Week1" do something)
```

Appreciate any comments/feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach using `any()` and testing for the week. I have created dummy data to show the example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(CowId) %>%
  mutate(Bacillus=ifelse(any(Bacillus[Week=='Week1']==1),1,0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   CowId [2]
  CowId Bacillus Week 
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
1  1234        1 Week1
2  1234        1 Week2
3  1234        1 Week3
4  1234        1 Week4
5  1235        0 Week1
6  1235        0 Week2
7  1235        0 Week3
8  1235        0 Week4
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(CowId = c(1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1235, 1235, 
1235, 1235), Bacillus = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Week = c("Week1", 
"Week2", "Week3", "Week4", "Week1", "Week2", "Week3", "Week4"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can create a logical vector with 'Bacillus' `&` the 'Week' where its value is 'Week1', subset the 'CowId', check whether it is in 'CowId', coerce the logical to binary (`+`)

```
df$Bacillus <- with(df, +(CowId %in% unique(CowId[as.logical(Bacillus) &
           Week == 'Week1'])))
df$Bacillus
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(CowId = c(1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1235, 1235, 
1235, 1235), Bacillus = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Week = c("Week1", 
"Week2", "Week3", "Week4", "Week1", "Week2", "Week3", "Week4"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```